# How to make use 'Typo' gem in an existing rails application, now it runs as separate blog engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am often pointed to the source of typo blog engine i.e., http://typosphere.org/stable.tar.gz But, if I download and perform the following: bundle install etc. it runs as a separate engine.

I tried installing typo as a gem, I tried the following:

```
gem install typo

typo install /some/path this fails, saying 'Typo command not found'
```

How to integrate typo blog engine with existing app, any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Typo is not a gem. It's an engine.

Comment: this URL suggests the contrary: http://rubygems.org/gems/typo

Comment: When it comes to installing things, rubygems.org's pre-generated 'instructions' are a lot less definitive than the readme, which see:  http://github.com/fdv/typo.

Comment: If it's an engine, is there a way to integrate it into a rails application & make it share the same database as the main application ?

Comment: I agree, I'd like to know this too. I mean, the other facts are interesting, but, could you reasonably integrate this into a current Rails 3 app using Devise/CanCan/Bootstrap? Of course this is a loaded quesion, I'm sure you *could* do anything, but is it worth the trouble or easier to build out your own....i wonder...

Answer (score 0):

`Typo` is a Rails project. I am happy to say that I contributed to it at one point of time.
You asked in comments, that you wish to use database of Typo in your main application. For that, I'll suggest you to check out [connection_ninja](https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja).

However, there are many gotchas with these type of configurations.

Good luck.
PS: Just noticed that this question was asked long ago. Ouch!